# Packages to move a line up and down in the text

Tags: text-editing

Please don't call me lazy, but has anybody compared all the available packages that allow to move a line up or down in the text? I have found:

- move-lines
- move-text
- move-dup
- drag-stuff

Or, just, to anybody who has chosen one of these over another, what made you prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`move-dup`](https://github.com/wyuenho/move-dup) offers a minor mode with commands to move or duplicate the current line or region. When operating on a region, it first expands the region to only contain whole lines. It also has an option, enabled by default, that combines them into single undo entries, so you can undo a whole batch of line-moves at once (though it does make undoing line-moves slightly slow).

[`move-text`](https://github.com/emacsfodder/move-text) offers commands to move lines or a region, and a command to set its default bindings (but no mode). When operating on a region that include partial lines, it only moves text that is actually in the region, which has some unusual behaviors and may be inconvenient to reverse without undoing. I would not recommend this package.

[`drag-stuff`](https://github.com/rejeep/drag-stuff.el) offers a minor mode and commands to move the current line or region. When operating on a region, it moves any line that contains any of the region, but does not expand the region. The mode offers simple customization of the keybindings (via `drag-stuff-modifier`), but you have to call `drag-stuff-define-keys` before you can actually use them. It also lets you drag words left and right (or the region left and right by characters).

[`move-lines`](https://github.com/targzeta/move-lines) is not in Melpa, so I won't look much at it, but I can see that it doesn't define a mode.

Personally, I'd say `drag-stuff` has the best behavior when it comes to moving a region (because it leaves the contents of the region alone), but `move-dup` is probably more convenient, because of how it amalgamates undo entries (which makes it much easier to put a line back where it came from without undoing more than you meant to).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently,

**move-text** and **move-lines** do the same thing, a difference is that the latter is not available from melpa.

**drag-stuff** adds the capability of moving selections to the right or left.

**move-dup** adds a different capability, that of duplicating a line or selection.